# What is 'little despite diminishing returns'?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I read a [blog](http://www.firstpost.com/politics/kejriwal-vs-jaitley-why-the-battle-is-going-to-go-nowhere-2554512.html) where I stuck here:

> Having started his career by levelling allegations against all politicians, Kejriwal has changed ***little despite diminishing returns on this tactic***.

I can't understand the meaning of the last portion of this sentence. To my mind, the writer wants to say that Kejriwal has changed his tactic, but then what is the meaning of 'little despite diminishing returns'? Is the above portion grammatical? What is the exact meaning of it?

Answer (score 2):

There should be a comma after little.

> Having started his career by leveling allegations against all politicians, Kejriwal has changed little, despite diminishing returns on this tactic.

That's still not great phrasing, I'd rearrange the whole sentence if I had wrote it.
Anyhow, it's saying that even though his initial tactic (leveling allegations) doesn't work as well as when he started his career, he still does it pretty much the same way. Maybe he's made small adjustments, but that's all.

edit: Here's the way I would phrase this sentence:

> Despite diminishing returns, Kejriwal has changed little from his initial tactic of leveling allegations against all politicians.

Answer (score 1):

*leveling* here means targeting and putting allegations on someone. The author wants to say that Kejriwal started his career by putting allegations on almost all politicians.

However, the *return* is **not good**. It is diminishing i.e. he's getting little and little response to his allegations. While most of media calls him champion in 'mudslinging', the author wants to say that *though he's getting *diminishing* returns, he has **not changed**.

In other words, *"Kejriwal, stop mudslinging, people don't like it, they don't respond all this in a positive way. Change your tactics."*

Comment: Is the sentence written correctly here? Can we make it simpler?

Comment: yes, it looks *absolutely okay* to me without any change. Use 'in spite of' instead of *despite* - is it now simpler?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of diminishing returns (more on it in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminishing_returns)) was popularized in the early 19th Century by such important British economists as Thomas Malthus and David Ricardo. In a nutshell:

If you double the number of seeds, you'd expect your crops to double, but they won't. You'll get less than double. If you triple the number of seeds, you'll get even less, proportionally. And so forth.

Or, if you invest a hundred dollars in some project and get two hundred in return, and assume that investing two hundred would get you four hundred, you'd be assuming wrong: you'll get less. The more you keep milking something, the weaker the return.

The sentence that puzzles you so means, roughly speaking, that even though Mr. Kejriwal's tactics have been getting less and less effective over the years, he has been unwilling to alter them dramatically: they're still (the tactics) pretty much the same as they were in the beginning of his career, and he is still the same old Kejriwal as he was back then ("He has changed little").

Comment: You could double your crops with double the seeds, as long as you also double the land – but the law is saying that you may not double your _profits_. (Sooner or later, you might have to build another silo, for example, and that would cut into your profits.) And the law of diminishing returns doesn't necesarily apply to an investment example, either. In short, I'm glad someone is taking time to explain the law, but I think your examples could be improved a little bit.

Comment: @J.R.: Now please consider this. Doubling your land would _immediately_ force you to double the labor; the management of the labor; etc. If there's only one water source, then, depending on its size, doubling your land might result in water shortages. There's always _something_. The law of diminishing returns NEVER sleeps. In order to dance around it, you must change your strategy COMPLETELY each time you increase the size of anything. We're still trying to apply 19th Century _elite_ methods to _mass_ education: the results are before us.

Comment: Yes, that explains it much better than your original answer. Thanks.